# How to read txt in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have a dataset with txt format like this:

```
1 1
0 1
1 0
11 12
11 13
13 13
12 8.5
```

I'll try to import dataset with pandas, and try to split the dataset
but it's a mess.
i need help to import data txt with transform split data txt.
after that i need to visulaize this data with simple DBSCAN.

```
filename = 'Data.txt'
arr = []
for line in filename :
    arr = line.split('\n')
    arr[1] = arr[1]
    arr[2] = arr[2]
    rows.append(arr)

print(rows)
```

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

By reading the documentation and looking at the example:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-dbscan-py
This should at least show you your data with matplot

```
filename = "data.txt"
arr = []
with open(filename,"r") as f:
    for line in f:
        arr.append(line.split())
x = np.array(arr)
db = DBSCAN(eps=3, min_samples=2).fit(x.astype(np.float64))
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)
unique_labels = set(labels)
colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(each) for each in np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels))]
for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
    if k == -1:
        # Black used for noise.
        col = [0, 0, 0, 1]

    class_member_mask = (labels == k)

    xy = x[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)

    xy = x[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2bXv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in most languages are 0 based for good reasons.

Hence the line

```
arr[2] = arr[2]
```

Is an **index out of bounds** access on two-column data.

If it would work, it woukd not have any effect. It's just nonsense...

Answer (score 0):

Read the file with a context manager which returns a list of lines:

```
with open('your_file.csv') as f:
    file = f.readlines()
```

Then append the first and second elements in each line as a tuple to your arr:

```
arr = []
for line in file:
    arr.append((line.split(',')[0], line.split(',')[1]))
```